# if project treble aims to separate the platform and vendor partitions, why is the kernel source code needed when building system.img (platform)

Tags: treble

if project treble aims to separate the platform and vendor partitions so they can be updated separately, why is the kernel source code needed when building system.img (platform) for AOSP, isn't the kernel source code provided by the vendor side?

p.s is the kernel source code used to build the core system/framework files or is it only used in the boot.img/recovery.img?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i mean for system-as-root devices it may require kernel source to build system.img

Comment: is the kernel source used to build the core system/framework files?

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions/system-as-root

Comment: do the core platform framework files in the system partition contain kernel specific code in a device which is not system as root?

Comment: consider self-answering your question here on android enthusiasts for sharing knowledge